# Completely removing scene (including all objects/materials it contained)

Tags: scripting, add-on, scene

I'm working on a Blender addon that will render multiple versions of a scene by altering node input parameters. To leave the scene unchanged, I want to render a copy of the current scene, which I successfully do. The problem is that when doing a full copy of a scene using `ops.scene.new(type="FULL_COPY")` it creates a copy of everything that existed in the original scene. When I later delete the new scene using `bpy.ops.scene.delete()` all those copied objects and materials still exists! How do I remove a scene and everything that was contained in it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider starting with a new blend file (empty), then you pass to addon the source blend file. The addon can link the scene/collection from the source file, render and remove linked. Then repeat the process.

Or, to follow your initial setup, you could put the whole scene in a "*root*" collection and then call `bpy.ops.outliner.collection_delete (hierarchy = True)`. In theory with *hierarchy = True* it should delete all the objects contained.